# How to count amount of elements in a row of a matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, input, limit

Using an integer array, Id like to first ask the user for the amount of rows and columns (lets call them x and y) he wants in the array (i know how to do this step). It is important though that while the user enters the values that will be stored in the matrix, that one row will be read in from one line of input, and the second row from the second line of input and so on. So one line of input=1 row.

So if he has defined x amount of columns, he should enter x numbers for the first row, all on one line. How can i check whether or not x numbers have indeed been entered on the line? If less or more are entered i will print an error message. Is there some kind of command that checks the size of 1 row, so that it can check it against the x that the user has defined?

The code I have written thus far involves the simple steps, but I have little ideas about how to implement this check, to confirm that the user is entering the same amount of inputs as he has defined originally.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do share the code written.

Comment: If you are using `scanf` the "rows" do not need to match. Whitespace is ignored so the values can be entered by separating with a space or newline as you please. If you enter too many values for one row before pressing `Enter` they are buffered ready for the next row. If you want to insist one row for input line, use `fgets` and then `sscanf` but you are making us ***guess***.

Comment: Note that `scanf` family of functions return the number of fields successfully input. You should always check that result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing is however, that I dont want the extra values to go to the next row. If the user defines x columns, i want x numbers on one line to be read into a row. If the user enters more or less than x numbers on that line i want it to appear as an error. So if i can check after every input whether or not the size of each row exceeds or is smaller than x, it would make this very simple. I just havent come across any way of finding the size of a row in an array.

Comment: The size of a row in an array is the size you defined it to be.

Comment: Explore `fgets` and `strtok`, using `sscanf` on the tokens extracted.

Comment: Or `fgets` and `strtol`. The `strtol` function takes an `endptr` that allows you to move the the next number on the line.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to read one line at a time, you should use `fgets` which does exactly that.  Then you can use `strtok` to separate the line by spaces/tabs and attempt to convert each value to an int.  If you run out of numbers before the row is filled, or still have more numbers after the row is filled, then you can alert the user of that.

Here's a quick example:

```
void read_array(int **array, int rows, int cols)
{
    char line[100];
    int i,count;
    char *p;

    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        printf("enter row %d: "), i-1);
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        count = 0;
        p = strtok(line, " \t");
        while (p && (count < cols)) {
            matrix[i][count++] = atoi(p);
            p = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        }
        if (count < cols) {
            printf("too few values\n");
            i--;
            continue;
        } else if (p) {
            printf("too many values\n");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you advise to use a char array? Do i just declare a char array in the same manner; Simply "char matrix[20][20];" for example?

Comment: @stellarhawk34 Given that you'll be asking the user for the number of rows and columns, you should allocate that memory dynamically.  You should define it as a `int **`, call `malloc` once for the rows, then a call to `malloc` for each row for the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, though the other answer is better than mine for your specific requirements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_rows;
    int number_of_columns;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_rows);
    printf("Ok, enter the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_columns);

    int matrix[number_of_rows][number_of_columns];

    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_rows; ++i) {
        printf("This is %d row.\n", i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < number_of_columns; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /* Print's the 2D array. */
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_rows; ++i) {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < number_of_columns; ++j) {
            printf("%d   ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What this does is ask the user for the number of rows and columns the user wants the matrix (2D array) to have, and then declares a 2D array based on those numbers. Then it loops through each row, printing to the console the number of the row before looping through each column. After the 2D array is initialized, it prints the 2D array the way one would draw a matrix. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a function to get an integer within a range and another to get a series of integers. `strtol` is used to parse the values from an input obtained using `fgets`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

//inputs
// char *line : pointer to text to be parsed
// char **next : pointer to pointer to allow modification of caller's pointer
// char *term : pointer to characters to be considered terminators
// int *value : pointer to int to allow modification of caller's int
// int min : minimum value of range
// int max : maximum value of range
// returns : 0 failure or 1 success
int get_int_range ( char *line, char **next, char *term, int *value, int min, int max)
{
    long int input = 0;
    char *end = NULL;//will point to end of parsed value

    errno = 0;
    input = strtol ( line, &end, 10);//get the integer from the line. end will point to the end of the parsed value
    if ( end == line) {// nothing was parsed. no digits
        printf ( "input MUST be a number\n");
        return 0;// return failure
    }
    // *end is the character that end points to
    if ( *end != '\0' && ( strchr ( term, *end) == NULL)) {// is *end '\0' or is *end in the set of term characters
        printf ( "problem with input: [%s] \n", line);
        return 0;
    }
    if ( ( errno == ERANGE && ( input == LONG_MAX || input == LONG_MIN))
    || ( errno != 0 && input == 0)){// parsing error from strtol
        perror ( "input");
        return 0;
    }
    if ( input < min || input > max) {// parsed value is outside of range
        printf ( "input out of range %d to %d\n", min, max);
        return 0;
    }

    if ( next != NULL) {// if next is NULL, caller did not want pointer to end of parsed value
        *next = end;// *next allows modification to caller's pointer
    }
    *value = input;// *value allows modification to callers int
    return 1;// success
}

//inputs
// int cols : needed to pass in the variable length array
// int dest[][cols] : variable length array to be modified with parsed values
// int inputrow : row of the variable length array to be modified
// int min : mininum value of range
// int max : maximum value of range
// char *line : pointer to text to be parsed
// char *term : pointer to characters to be considered terminators
// returns : 0 failure or 1 success
int get_int_series ( int cols, int dest[][cols], int inputrow, int min, int max, char *line, char *term)
{
    char *end = NULL;// will point to end of parsed value
    char *each = NULL;// will point to start of parsed value
    int valid = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int temp[cols];// temporary storage for parsed values

    each = line;// each points to start of line
    do {
        valid = get_int_range ( each, &end, term, &input, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);// call to parse one value
        if ( !valid) {// failure
            printf ( "input MUST be a number\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if ( valid) {// success
            temp[count] = input;// save parsed value in temporary array
            count++;
            if ( count > cols) {
                printf ( "too many integers. %d entered. only enter %d\n", count, cols);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        // *end is the character that end points to
        while ( *end && strchr ( term, *end)) {// if *end not '\0' and *end is in the set of term characters
            end++;// yes. advance end one position
        }
        each = end;// set the end pointer to be the new starting pointer
    } while ( end && *end);// keep looping the above while end is not NULL and *end is not '\0' 

    if ( count < cols) {
        printf ( "too few integers. need %d entered. only entered %d\n", cols, count);
        return 0;
    }
    while ( count) {
        count--;
        dest[inputrow][count] = temp[count];// set the values in the callers array to the values in the temporary array
    }
    return 1;// success
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[900] = {'\0'};
    int valid = 0;
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    int eachrow = 0;
    int eachcol = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "Enter number of array rows or quit\n");
        fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), stdin);//read a line
        if ( strcmp ( line, "quit\n") == 0) {
            return 1;// if quit is entered, exit the program
        }
        valid = get_int_range ( line, NULL, "\n", &rows, 0, INT_MAX);// call to parse a value
    } while ( !valid);// on failure, keep looping the above

    do {
        printf ( "Enter number of array columns or quit\n");
        fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), stdin);//read a line
        if ( strcmp ( line, "quit\n") == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        valid = get_int_range ( line, NULL, "\n", &cols, 0, INT_MAX);
    } while ( !valid);

    //once the size is obtained, the variable length array can be declared
    int array[rows][cols];

    for(eachrow = 0; eachrow < rows; eachrow++) {// loop through the rows
        do {
            printf ( "Enter %d integers for row %d or quit. Ex 1 2 3\n", cols, eachrow + 1);
            fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), stdin);//read a line
            if ( strcmp ( line, "quit\n") == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            valid = get_int_series ( cols, array, eachrow, INT_MIN, INT_MAX, line, " \n");// call to obtain a series of values
        } while ( !valid);// on failure, keep looping the above
    }
    // show the values in the variable length array
    for(eachrow = 0; eachrow < rows; eachrow++) {
        for(eachcol = 0; eachcol < cols; eachcol++) {
            printf("[%d] ", array[eachrow][eachcol]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nDone\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Could you briefly explain how your functions work however? Im not sure i entirely understand from reading the code. For example why is the number of columns or arrays read as a character and not an integer?

Comment: Could you also explain the function of the "**next" pointer. Im having difficulty understanding what it does exactly within the range function.