# Read a string and convert it to 2D int matrix C

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix, char

I want to try and have the user input the rows to a specific matrix (dimensions are user defined, with a maximum of 15x15) into a character string. I then want to try and scan this string for the amount of spaces in order to ensure that if the user has specified 5 columns, that only 5 entries are being entered per line by the user. So if user specifies 5x5 matrix, he should enter on one line:

1 2 3 4 5.

Then on the next,

6 7 8 9 10 and so on.

Each line of input should correspond to one row. So if the amount of spaces exceeds 4 for example, I will know the user entered more than he should have per line. I then want to somehow segment this string after reading in all rows and convert it to a 2d integer array in order for it to be eligible for matrix addition or multiplication afterwards.
Does anyone have any hint as to how to go about doing this, if the problem description makes sense?

Comment: what have done so far?

Comment: It would be more reliable (and user friendly) to count the numbers, not the spaces.

Comment: See similar [recently asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663153/how-to-count-amount-of-elements-in-a-row-of-a-matrix-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have an array of string:

```
char string[N];

int spaces_num=0,i=0,last_spaces=0;

while(true)
{
  scanf('%s',string);//Perhaps ma need a better way to read user input
  //loop the folowing code until user not needed for user input
  while(string[i]!=='\0' && i < N)
  {
     if(string[i]==' ') spaces_num++;
     i++;
  }

  if(last_spaces>0 && spaces_num!=last_spaces)
  {
    break;
  }
  else
  {
   last_spaces=spaces_num;
  }
}
```

I hope it works the code above may need fixing but it is just ti give an idea of the solution. Do not take too literally.

Comment: There are some syntax errors in this, and I can't see where the index is increased.

Comment: It is to give some idea on the solution. I have to write ANSI C for Ages.

Comment: `string[i]!=='\0' || i < N` looks like a bug to me -- You want a `&&` there.

Comment: Comments are not supposed to say thanks. But Thanks for telling the bug. I fixed it